# Update rows if one or multiple conditions exist in a dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to update specific rows if one or multiple conditions exist:

**Data**

```
ID  Date    stat            en
AA  Q2.22   hi              10
AA  Q2.22   hi              11
AA  Q2.22   hi              11
AA  Q1.22   hi              12
AA  Q1.22   bye             14
BB  Q4.22   bye             14.3
CC  Q3.22   ok              18.4
CC  Q3.22   ok              18.4
CC  Q3.22   ok              18.4
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date    stat            en
AA  Q2.22                   0
AA  Q2.22                   0
AA  Q2.22                   0
AA  Q1.22                   0
AA  Q1.22                   0
BB  Q4.22   bye             14.3
CC  Q3.22   ok              18.4
CC  Q3.22   ok              18.4
CC  Q3.22   ok              18.4
```

**Doing**

```
df.loc[(df.ID =='AA') & (df.Date == 'Q1.22' or 'Q2.22'), [ 'stat'] = '', ['en'] = 0
```

Any suggestion is appreciated, I am still researching.

Answer (score 2):

Let's update the values in multiple columns using boolean indexing:

```
mask = df['ID'].eq('AA') & df['Date'].isin(['Q2.22', 'Q1.22'])
df.loc[mask, ['stat', 'en']] = ['', 0]
```

---

```
   ID   Date stat    en
0  AA  Q2.22        0.0
1  AA  Q2.22        0.0
2  AA  Q2.22        0.0
3  AA  Q1.22        0.0
4  AA  Q1.22        0.0
5  BB  Q4.22  bye  14.3
6  CC  Q3.22   ok  18.4
7  CC  Q3.22   ok  18.4
8  CC  Q3.22   ok  18.4
```